# Multiply columns of a pandas Dataframe by different scalars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with columns `col_1, col_2, ..., col_n`.

I want to multiply each column of the pandas Dataframe by a different scalar based on the column. For example, multiply each of the elements in `col_1` by `n_1`, each of the elements in `col_2` by `n_2` etc... **What is the neatest way to do this?**

Currently my solution involves creating the dictionary `{col_1: n_1, col_2: n_2, ...}`. I then create a dataframe out of this with constant columns. This dataframe has the same columns as `df` and the values in each column are looked up from the dictionary.

I then multiply `df` and `df_2`.

I am using Python 2.7.10 and pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df[cols].values*np.array([2,3,4,5,6]), columns=cols)` you can try direct multiplication

Answer (score 3):

If you have no problem with hardcoded scalers, there is a pythonic way to do so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4],

                   'degrees': [360, 180, 360]},

                  index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])
df * [1, 2]
```

output

```
    angles  degrees
circle  0   720
triangle    3   360
rectangle   4   720
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary and `mul`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
df.mul({'col1': 2, 'col2': 10})
```

input:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

output:

```
   col1  col2
0     2    40
1     4    50
2     6    60
```